# Show characters typed while typing (on the fly)

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax, chat

In the introduction video of Google Wave they talk about a problem with chat in webapplications. In many webapplications you see a message like: `<name> is typing..` (before the message is submitted)

Google came up with an idea "to show each character typed while typing" to avoid this annoying message.

How do you create something like that??

Comment: you can do with multiple things , event keyup you can make a ajax call to back end and show the results , i implemented the same on www.art.com , type three characters in search box , you will see results.If you want more details u can ask me i will explain in detail

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were writing a solution, I would use PHP sockets and use the UDP protocol which is more fitting for this scenario. UDP protocol is unreliable but much much faster than TCP which is most commonly used for communication. So I guess I would have a very lightweight PHP script that would send a couple bytes of data to a processing server using UDP. Use AJAX to send data to the PHP script. There will be of course delay, but UDP will speed up the transaction significantly.

Comment: UDP is lossy. As a multimedia transport it's fine. With text however, you wouldn't want to receive a message like: Hell, wold!

Comment: The entire chat message would be transferred using TCP when the message is "committed" but for when the user is typing, UDP would be perfect. UDP might be lossy, but the good thing is you can send many packets at low cost and quickly.

Comment: Does anyone know which protocol Google is using? And I doubt that Google is using PHP.

Comment: I don't think Google releases that kind of information, but you could easily find out using a network sniffer.

Comment: @Samuel, I just found: http://www.waveprotocol.org and guess what.. Wave is open source :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use some form of bidirectional communication between the browser and the server. So the browser would communicate to the server every charcter that has been typed and the server would send that event to all the other browsers. This can be done through various techniques mostly known as [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) or reverse Ajax, in HTML5 it can be done via WebSockets. Here is a list of [Comet server implementations](http://cometdaily.com/maturity.html).